# is guava-libraries available in maven repo?

Tags: java, maven, guava

I am looking to find guava-libraries in maven repository.  It looks like guava is adding more features to google-collections library.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Starting from r03, Guava releases may be found in the central Maven repository.

You may include Guava by adding the following dependency to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

*Note: the above version number may be outdated when you read this. To know the latest available version, you may look [here](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/)*

Version updated on 19th Oct 2017.

Comment: As of 7/27/2010, releases "r05" and "r06" are also in the central repo. http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/

Comment: The guava-io, guava-primitives, etc. subprojects have been abandoned. There's just guava, now.

Comment: I updated my answer to point to r06, and removed mentions of the now abandoned guava subprojects. I also made it a "community wiki", so that people may update the version number as necessary :)

Comment: As of April 8 2011, it's now up to r09.

Comment: And for GWT users, change the `artifactId` to `guava-gwt`.

Comment: I could only find guava-gwt for R10 on the repository, and I need r08

Answer (score 11):

[Bintray's JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) is a superset of Maven Central as includes libraries from various repositories. Here's [Google Guava](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.google.guava%3aguava/view).

You can click on "Set me up!" to get the instructions on how to configure your build tool to resolve from JCenter and on the "i" on a jar file to get the dependency declaration for your build tool.

You can also become a watcher to get notifications on new versions.

Answer (score 6):

[mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com/) is your friend.  It has an index of maven repository space with maven, ivy and other details about artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all guava maven repositories here:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava

Answer (score 0):

Find latest guava(version 17.0) maven repositories http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/17.0

Comment: While that’s true, the OP will surely prefer to include it in the POM, as shown in the accepted answer.

Comment: but i have given only link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Guava: Google Core Libraries For Java: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava