# how to count variable of a list of objects in java?

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have a List of object as `List<Human> humanList;`
which human object consist of 5 variable as firstname, lastname,color,length,sex.

**How can i check out to see the variable(firstname) how many times appear/exist in the list?**

```
    List<Human> humanList = getHumanList();
    for(Human human :humanList){

    }
```

Comment: What do mean by "sits in the list"? do you mean it's not null?

Comment: Clarify your problem please. It isn't clear as currently stated.

Comment: I means How many times appear in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming here `firstname` is of type `String`, if it is not - change it as needed.

Create a [`Map<String,Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (let it be `map`) which will be used as a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram).

Iterate the list, and for each human:

```
Integer temp = map.get(human.firstName); //search for the current number of occurances
if (temp == null) map.put(human.firstName, 1); //first occurance of this firstname
else map.put(human.firstName,temp+1); //not first occurance, modify the map.
```

When you are done `map` holds each `firstName` as a key and the number of its occurances as the matching value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use guava multiset count method http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained.

```
Multiset<Human> set = HashMultiset.create();
        set.count(Human.firstName);
```

Comment: Is there a Maven dependency for guava?

Comment: Yes, if the class Human's equals and hashCode are based on firstName only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550441/is-guava-libraries-available-in-maven-repo

Comment: i get the maven dependency, now i gonna test it. Just one think, how doe you means by (hashCode are based on firstName)? can you give me a example?

Answer (score 1):

You need to traverse the list counting occurences `O(N)`.
A better option if you need this often would be to increment a counter as you add/remove from the list and use that instead of traversing